# Onboard Bluetooth no longer working after 21.10 upgrade

Tags: bluetooth, 21.10

Since updating from 21.04 to 21.10, my onboard bluetooth from my ryzen 7 board (Asus PB50) has stopped working. As it was fine before the update, I am a bit befuddled as to why this is.

Running dmesg | grep -i blue doesn't return any results, so it seems that the hardward isn't even being seen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with LiveUSB.

Comment: I'm sorry @Pilot6, I don't fully understand what you meant there.

Comment: Boot from LiveUSB and check if BT works.

Comment: As a follow up, LiveUSB didn't work, but a later install did. There was some juggling of BIOS settings, that I have to assume changed something in there, though it was haphazard and I cannot say for sure.

I am 90% sure that the rtw88_* drivers are working fine naturally, but that the BT chip was getting lost in the handoff from firm to soft ware.

That said, thanks for the help @Pilot6.